# How make buttons and input boxs appear in single line

Tags: css, html, css-float

Hi friends i have following piece of code. It works fine in firefox but in chrome and internet explorer it looks very ugly. In this code the input boxes and buttons are not appearing in proper single line. Their alignment is very bad. How can i make them appear exact in single line without even small error.

```
  <style>
#header
{
background:#243342;
color:#dcdcdc;
height:55px;
min-width:960px;
padding-left:20px;
padding-right:50px;
}
#header a
{
text-decoration:none;
}
</style>

<div id='header'>
<div style='float:left;'>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="url" id="url" class='input-normal'  onblur="if (this.value == &quot;&quot;) {this.value = &quot;http://example.com&quot;;}" onfocus="if (this.value == &quot;http://example.com&quot;) {this.value = &quot;&quot;;}" value="http://example.com"/>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class='button-normal' id='button-go-responser' onClick="loadsite();">Go</button></div>
</div>
<div style='float:right'>
Custom width:<input type="text" id="custom_width" class='input-normal input-small'/>
Custom height:<input type="text" id="custom_height" class='input-normal input-small'/>
<button type="submit" id="button-set-custom" onClick = "set_custom();" class='button-normal'>Set</button></div>
<div style='clear:both'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: They seem to be in a single line for me in Chrome. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S8hSU/)

Comment: me too, it looks **the same** in FireFox and other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `min-width` attribute and adding a proper property for width for them. Once they're perfect in size then IE would render them in one line.